# How to deploy a site?

Tags: composer, deployment

I have Drupal 8 website created with composer. I put all files to my remote server in the sitename/www/ but my page won't load. I receive such an error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel' not found in /home/bx273629/drupal8.com.ua/www/index.php on line 16

I think it is because I created that website with the Composer. Does any body know how to deploy correctly such a websites?

Website perfectly works locally!

I have such an error:

> 'Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home/bx273629/drupal8.com.ua/www/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/pear/php56') in /home/bx273629/drupal8.com.ua/www/autoload.php on line 17'

And on the line 17 of these file I have such a string:

```
return require DIR . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

It is from the outer folder which was installed with composer.

Comment: Have you tried to run: `composer update`?

Comment: For what? Where?

Comment: Composer is not for deploying a site, but for copying all the dependencies. In the sites where I don't have access to a remote shell, I just copy with FTP the files on the remote server, after I copied all the dependencies with Composer, in local.

Comment: It sounds like you aren't copying all the files.

Comment: I use filezilla to replace all content of web folder to my remote server

Comment: I have such an error 'Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home/bx273629/drupal8.com.ua/www/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/pear/php56') in /home/bx273629/drupal8.com.ua/www/autoload.php on line 17' and on the line 17 of these file I have such a string 'return require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php'; It is from the outer folder which was installed with comsposer

Comment: Follow this https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/install

Comment: My website works perfect locally! I cannot ,make it working on the remote server!

Answer (score 1):

I had faced this problem a while ago. After lot of research, I found that running 
`composer install` from the site root resolves any problem.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/99101)

Comment: I had faced this problem a while ago, after lots of research, I found the step I mentioned clear the problem. Hence I thought of sharing it. I did not have any questions or asked any questions in my response! @mradcliffe, I am not sure why this does not qualify as an answer.  can you please explain?

Comment: When answering a question, avoid starting with _try with_, or users will think you are trying to get feedback from the OP, as if you weren't sure about that working, and you needed a feedback from the user who asked the question to give a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy your `vendor/` folder (generated by `composer update` on your local) into `/home/bx273629/drupal8.com.ua/` dir (one level above `www/`), then `index.php` and rest files into `/home/bx273629/drupal8.com.ua/www/` as normally **`vendor/` folder should be copied one level above of Drupal root** (so it's not accessible from the outside), so the file `www/../vendor/autoload.php` will exists (same localization as on local).

If you cannot copy to the folder above your docroot (`www/`) due to access restriction, modify your `autoload.php` to point to the current folder, e.g.

```
return require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

and copy the `vendor/` along with your Drupal files.

Comment: I did this but now has an error Fatal error: Class 'Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel' not found in /home/bx273629/drupal8.com.ua/www/index.php on line 16 in that line I have follwoing code $kernel = new DrupalKernel('prod', $autoloader);

Comment: @rick1 Have you run `composer update` command in you Drupal root directory on your local to download dependencies?

Comment: yes but it won't work. I mean I have the same error

Comment: @rick1 Do you still have error about opening `www/../vendor/autoload.php`? are you sure the file exists there?